# How can I modify the schema by using Microsoft.Phone.Data.Linq.DatabaseSchemaUpdater?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

It seems that the DatabaseSchemaUpdater is only used to add new table/column, but it could not be used to modify the database schema.

Can anyone tell me how can I modify the database schema(drop column) by using DatabaseSchemaUpdater? Or other ways to make it happen.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh394022(v=vs.105).aspx